# Java - stop function from its normal run

Tags: java

Is there any easy way such as `break` for whiles to stop/skip a running function?

```
public void a(){
   do_this();
   //break the function here
   do_that(); //do not load this
}
```

What I want to approach could be done with boolean and if statements as well, but I was wondering if there was some shortcut command in order to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void a(){
   do_this();
   if(1==1)
       return;
   do_that(); //do not load this
}
```

Just curious, why do you want to write such a code?

Comment: `if (1==1)` are you joking :-P, why not just `if(true)`

Comment: Oh, return with void ;P

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson That would probably result in following error: `break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch`

Comment: Oh, ok. I was thinking it was a loop for some reason.

Comment: I guess the best answer should be to comment out the method that is not required :) :D `// do_that();`

Answer (score 0):

let the first function return a boolean that indicates if the calling function should move on:

```
public void a(){
    boolean doContinue = do_this();
    if(doContinue) {
       do_that();
    }
}
```

i you ALWAYS want to skip the second part, it's dead code. you could just remove it.

**Always have in mind that your code should be readable for other programmers!**

Comment: i understand. i missunderstood the last sentence. sorry for that.